# How to Wrap CheckBox Labels

Tags: sapui5

I'm using `sap.m` to build a simple mobile app. I've made a VBox to hold a few check boxes and embedded it in a Page.

The width of the box is neatly the width of the screen (320px in the iPhone 5 device mode on Chrome). The labels of the checkboxes do not adhere to this width and simply grow beyond.

```
var oTicks = new sap.m.VBox();
oTicks.addItem(new sap.m.CheckBox({
    name: 'name',
    text: 'Are the tools and equipment I am going to use in safe working order?'
}));
```

As you can see in the screenshot here, the label of the third check box is > 320px (it's 454 to be exact).

[image: checkbox]

Is there any way I can "wrap" the label so that it pushes the other items down, and fits the text inside the box?

Comment: For readers using UI5 1.54 and above, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614375/5846045. Avoid using custom CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a StyleClass to the CheckBox and use `white-space: normal`. SAPUI5 automatically put `white-space:` to `no-wrap`.

**Edited to Jorgs final solution!**

Example:

```
oTicks.addStyleClass('YourClassName');
```

In CSS:

```
.YourClassName label {
   white-space: normal;
   line-height: normal;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Your comment about `white-space` was correct. However, I ended up applying the class to the `Checkbox`, and the css was `.YourClassName label`. Apparently it's only the label that deviates (vbox and children are set to `normal`). This is for UI5 1.26.x in any case. I also added `line-height: normal` and `vertical-align: middle`, otherwise it flows onto the next label. If you add it to your answer I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

[As of version 1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/175e0a829b33aa02eab9afed9115909a8ea88103), `sap.m.CheckBox` supports the property `wrapping` with which the control can determine whether the label's text should wrap or not. Default value is `false` (no wrapping).

### Demo

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], Core => Core.attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], (XMLView, JSONModel) => XMLView.create({
  definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" height="100%">
    <App>
      <Page title="Checkbox Wrapping">
        <headerContent>
          <Switch state="{/wrapping}"
            customTextOff=" "
            customTextOn=" "
          />
        </headerContent>
        <VBox width="320px" backgroundDesign="Solid">
          <CheckBox
            text="Are the tools and equipment I'm going to use in safe working order?"
            wrapping="{/wrapping}"
          />
        </VBox>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>`,
  models: new JSONModel({ wrapping: false }),
}).then(view => view.placeAt("content")))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3_dark"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```